# How do I display the name of a user, in Facebook, using their uid?

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbml, xfbml, uid

I am loading the JavaScript SDK Asynchronously for my iframe canvas application.

I am aware that fbml is deprecated and being phased out, but is xfbml still ok?

Can I still use fb:name eg. `<fb:name uid="2901279">`?

Is there a better way to print the names of 100 friends for a user, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start using the Graph API, here's a quick *working* example to get you started:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<title>Facebook Javascript SDK</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div><fb:login-button perms=""></fb:login-button></div>

    <div id="friends"></div>


    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId   : 'APP_ID',
          cookie  : true,
          status  : true,
          xfbml   : true 
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });

        FB.api('/me/friends',function(resp) {
            if(resp && resp.data.length) {
                var html = '<ul>';
                for(var i=0; i<resp.data.length; i++) {
                    html += '<li><img src="http://graph.facebook.com/' + resp.data[i].id + '/picture?type=small" />' + resp.data[i].name + '</li>';
                }
                html += '</ul>';
                document.getElementById('friends').innerHTML = html;
            }
        });
      };

      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Just replace with your application id and you are good to go!

Answer (score 1):

You have right, you probably shouldn't use `fbml` any longer, but all markup from "social plugin" will be still encourage (i. e. `like button`).

No matter is it deprecated or not, I prefer got full controll of layout my app - Instead use `<fb:name...` tag, you could get all friends list from "http://graph.facebook.com/UID/friends" and parse resulting `JSON`. (in PHP-SDK: `$fb->api("/me/friends");`).